# Is there any way to increase memory limit and execution time limit in CLion IDE?

Tags: c++, ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

I would like to increase the memory limit i.e. **512MB** and increase execution time limit(if there is an execution time limit in the IDE) i.e **10sec** in CLion IDE. How can I achieve that?